# Using the Raspberry Pi as Webserver and btsync

Tags: web-server, static-ip

My Raspberry Pi has an internal IP address of say `192.168.1.5` and I'm running a webserver on this IP address. If I navigate from my Macbook to this address I'm met with my current website. I'd like to host btsync as well on this machine but if I visit the default port and IP binding for btsync, `192.168.1.5:8888`, on my Macbook the browser spins for a while and eventually times out. What is the correct way to setup a webserver instance and btsync instance so that I can access the btsync Web Admin page?

Answer (score 2):

You can check the status with the following command:

```
sudo service btsync status
```

(re-)start it with:

```
sudo service btsync restart
```

Or maybe you misconfigured something, so you could start a reconfiguration via:

```
dpkg-reconfigure btsync
```

Answer (score 0):

Try going to `192.168.1.5` or `192.168.1.5:80`, it may just be that btsync is using the defalt port of all webserver which is `80`.

Comment: I believe when I setup btsync from the command line it had the option of specifiying the port so I used 8888 by default so when I visit 192.168.1.5:8888 the browser just spins for a long time and timesout. Could there be some configuration I have to make with nginx?